# Script to check passwordless connectivity between servers

Tags: shell, ssh

I have the following script. My requirement is if I give the username and IP address the script should check whether the host server has passwordless connectivity with the given server.

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter username"
read user
echo "Enter IP address"
read ip
echo "Enter condition"
read conditon
if [ $condition == "test" ]
then
        ssh -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey' $user@$ip "echo"
fi
```

The above script checks for passwordless connectivity and exits. I want the script to return "success" if the connection is there or "No connection" if there is no passwordless connection between the hosts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give an extra option to `ssh` that sets it in `BatchMode`

> **`BatchMode`**
>                If set to `yes`, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.  This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be `yes` or `no` (the default).
>
> **<sup>source: `man sshconfig`</sup>**

The following line will return the requested error code

```
ssh -oBatchMode=yes user@server echo  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will return `0` if it can log in and will return a non-zero value (255) if it fails to login.

So you could do something like:

```
ssh -oBathMode=yes "${user}@${server}" echo > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Success" || echo "No Connection"
```

Or you could even let the server answer Success as

```
ssh -oBathMode=yes "${user}@${server}" echo Success  2>/dev/null || echo "No Connection"
```

Comment: Fix the command below, as BatchMode instead of BathMode

Answer (score 0):

### Prerequisites

- Access to command line/terminal window
- User with *sudo* or *root* privileges
- A local server & a remote server
- SSH access to a remote server via *command line/terminal window*

---

### Before You Start

Check for existing SSH Keys, using the below command

```
ls -al ~/.ssh/id_*.pub
```

If the output tells you there are no such files, move on to the next step, which shows you how to generate SSH keys.

---

### Step 1: Generate SSH Key Pair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@domain.com"
```

- Next, type in the path where you want to store the keys or hit
  ***Enter*** to accept the **default path**.
- It also asks you to set a passphrase, this is to ensure more secure connection. Note that, the Passphrase may be interrupted when you set up automated processes. Else, one can just press ***Enter*** to **skip** this step.
- The output shows you the identification & about where is your *public key* stored along with the *key fingerprints*.

Verify your newly created SSH key pair, using the below command.

```
ls -al ~/.ssh/id_*.pub
```

---

### Step 2: Uploading the Public Key to Remote Server

There are 2 options, that one can adopt:

1. Using ***ssh-copy-id*** Command
2. Using ***cat*** Command

---

**Using ***ssh-copy-id*** command**

```
ssh-copy-ide [remote_username]@[server_ip_address]
```

**Using ***cat*** Command**

```
ssh [remote_username]@[server_ip_address] mkdir -p .ssh
```

Type in the password for remote server, and then *cat* to view the contents of the stored Public Key

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh [remote_username]@[server_ip_address] 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

---

### Step 3: Log in to Server Without Password

Final step is to check whether the setup works fine or not.

```
ssh [remote_username]@[server_ip_address]
```

---

### Troubleshooting, if found any errors

If you are still prompted for a password after going through all the steps, start by editing **file permissions** on the remote server.

1. **Set permissions 700** for the *.ssh* directory.
2. **Set permissions 640** for the *.ssh/authorized_keys* directory.

Edit file permissions using this command:

```
ssh [remote_username]@[server_ip_address] "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

---

### References:

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/52744882/18154805)